# Problem with Python3 picking Python2 package

Tags: 12.04, python

I installed `python3-numpy` package, but trying to import it in Python3 interpreter I get this:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, May  3 2012, 15:54:42) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zetah/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from version import git_revision as __git_revision__
ImportError: No module named version
>>>
```

Looking in Synaptic I see `python3-numpy` is installed in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/`

Why is it picking wrong package and what can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Please, add your last update as an answer and accept it. That will be better than closing the question.

Answer (score 2):

In my `~/.profile` file, probably following some online suggestion, I had this line:

`export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

so PYTHONPATH env was pointing to folder where I build local Python packages (from source)

Removing above line from `~/.profile` (which BTW could have been declared in `~/.bashrc` also) resolves this issue and works perfectly. Even more exporting PYTHONPATH is unnecessary, as I found out soon

Hope it helps someone